# custom ztick labels on surf plot, using PyPlot

Tags: julia

Looking for custom zticklabels and fontsize too on the z-axis.  Most notably the intuitive approach of using zticks([-(R+r),0,R+r],["-R-r","0","R+r"],fontsize=16) does not work.  I am using Julia 4.3.0 because this is an older project which I cannot fully convert to a newer version at this time.  The commented lines below include additional commands I tried which were unsuccessful.

**My final goal here is to get the -0.8, 0, 0.8 values on the z-axis to instead say "-r", and "0" and "r" respectively.**

```
using PyPlot

colormapp = "nipy_spectral"

R = 1.6;
r = 0.8;
N = 256;

dx = 2*pi/(N-1);
y = zeros(N,1); # y = phi (col) toroidal
x = y.'; # x = theta (row) poloidal
for ix = 2:N; y[ix] = (ix-1)*dx; x[ix] = (ix-1)*dx; end

cosxsqr = cos(x) .+ 0.0*y;
sinxsqr = sin(x) .+ 0.0*y;
sinysqr = 0.0*x .+ sin(y);
cosysqr = 0.0*x .+ cos(y);
Rrcosxsqr = R+r*cosxsqr;
rRrcosx = r*Rrcosxsqr[:];
Xsqr = Rrcosxsqr.*cosysqr;
Ysqr = Rrcosxsqr.*sinysqr;
Zsqr = r*sinxsqr;

figure(98)
clf()
pmeshtor = pcolormesh(x,y,Zsqr+r,cmap=colormapp);
cb = colorbar();

colorvals = Zsqr+r;
colorvals = colorvals/maximum(colorvals[:])

ax = figure(99)
clf()
srf = surf(Xsqr,Ysqr,Zsqr,cstride=10,rstride=10,facecolors=get_cmap(colormapp).o((colorvals)))
cb = colorbar(pmeshtor,ticks=[0,0.8,1.6])
cb[:ax][:set_yticklabels](["-r","0","r"], fontsize=16)
xlabel("x",fontsize=16)
ylabel("y",fontsize=16)
zlabel("z",fontsize=16)
xlim([-(R+r)-0.3,R+r+0.3])
ylim([-(R+r)-0.3,R+r+0.3])
zlim([-(R+r)-0.3,R+r+0.3])
xticks([-(R+r),0,R+r],["-R-r","0","R+r"],fontsize=16)
yticks([-(R+r),0,R+r],["-R-r","0","R+r"],fontsize=16)
zticks([-r,0,r])

#zticklabels([-r,0,r],["-r","0","r"])  
#setp(ax[:get_zticklabels](),fontsize=16);
#setp(ax[:set_zticklabels](["-r","0","r"]))#,fontsize=16);
```

Here is the resulting image.
[image]

Comment: can you provide a link for this( `x = y.'; # x = theta (row) poloidal`) syntax ?

Comment: past hashtag is a comment

Comment: and that `x=y.'` is correct i mean what is `y dot '` ? I wanted link for this syntax.

Comment: i did not find a julia doc, but it is matlab-like syntax where the .' turns a row into a column or vice versa.  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/399077-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-transposing-a-matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commented command

```
setp(ax[:set_zticklabels](["-r","0","r"]),fontsize=16);
```

does work, but only if insert missing projection option as follows in Fig 99

```
figure(99)
ax = subplot(111, projection="3d")
```